# Powershell script does not get executed by Task Scheduler

Tags: windows, command-line, powershell, scheduled-tasks

I have a simple Powershell script (ps1 file) that clears the contents of a existing file, and then appends date and status of a service to the file:

```
Clear-Content \\MyDomain\Homes\Usr\MyUser\"Mijn Documenten"\Desktop\ScriptOutput\test.txt
Get-Date -Format "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss" | Out-File -encoding ascii \\MyDomain\Homes\Usr\MyUser\"Mijn Documenten"\Desktop\ScriptOutput\test.txt -NoNewline 
" : " | Out-File -encoding ascii \\MyDomain\Homes\Usr\MyUser\"Mijn Documenten"\Desktop\ScriptOutput\test.txt -NoNewline -append 
(Get-Service MyService).status | Out-File -encoding ascii \\MyDomain\Homes\Usr\MyUser\"Mijn Documenten"\Desktop\ScriptOutput\test.txt -NoNewline -append
```

When executing this script (right click -> run with Powershell) the folder **ScriptOutput** on my desktop is populated with the file **test.txt** with the following contents:

```
2021-12-22 11:41:54 : Running
```

When I try to schedule this task for every 5 minutes using the Task Scheduler, I can see the Powershell window pop up every 5 minutes for a split second but the file (test.txt) is not populated with the most recent data. I am expecting a different timestamp for every time the script is executed.

Properties of the task are:

**General**

[image]

**Trigger (daily) (every 5 minutes)**

[image]

**Actions**

[image]

Where Program / scripts :

```
C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe
```

And Parameters :

```
-File C:\Scripts\FNMS Scripts\Beacon Server Service Logging Script\beaconscript_v1.0.ps1
```

**Why wont the script execute and update test.txt with the most recent timestamp?**

Comment: add `-ExecutionPolicy Bypass` before `-File C:\...` in your arguments

Answer (score 1):

That is happening because of [Window's Execution policy](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_execution_policies?view=powershell-7.2#long-description), Which does not allow an unsigned script to be run by default. You need to change this policy for your script to work.

1. Open an elevated Powershell prompt.
2. Type `Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted` to set the policy to Unrestricted.
3. Type `Get-ExecutionPolicy` to verify the current settings for the execution policy.

Please note that changing this setting is a security threat as malicious scripts can also be run by other programs. Instead you can try to write a Batch script spinoff of the same script, and then use that instead of this. Windows exeution policy don't block Batch script.

Comment: Okay that makes some kind of sense. I am unable to change the execution policy so I think i'll recreate the script in just bash. Thanks!

Comment: I stand corrected. I can change the policy and I have. All policies are changed to Unrestricted . Even now the script is not running correctly. Even after activating the task and right click -> Execute the file is not being updated. I can see the powershell screen pop up but its empty. Executing the script by right click run in powershell still works.

Comment: Also, in the Task Scheduler screen I can see an error as a result which is : 0xFFFD0000

Comment: the error should be included in your question